# BitBucket server merge commit history view

Tags: bitbucket-server

BitBucket Server 7.5, For the below scenarios,
1. branch is merged to another branch (could be from one repo to same repository or another repository)
2. commit merge with cherry-pick to another branch or repository

The BitBucket server copies the entire commit history.
It makes confusion on the commit history view in BitBucket User Interface.

If you see the commit history in the screen BitBucket UI view, It brings the merge commit history with timestamp instead of actual merge commit timestamp. Is there any way to see the actual commit history in BitBucket server User Interface?